# drop down list in excel2016

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, dropdownlist

I have created drop down list as per attached image. but the problem is I have long list of same item, the drop down list shows the same item as much as my data contain. is there any solution? As seen in image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4SUb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the auxiliary column can help.

Like Reddy Lutonadio said, you may use the Remove Duplicates function.

Or you could use formula to get the unique value from your source data.

I made a sample in column A as yours, then I enter the formula below in cell **C2**,
`=INDEX($A$2:$A$99,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(C$1:C1,$A$2:$A$99),0))&""`

Press **Ctrl+ Shift+ Enter**, and pull down to get the unique value.

[image]

Then you could set the cells from C2 to C99 or other cells of column C as a data source for Data Validation. If you add new data in Column A, it would be added into drop down list automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your range of data for the dropdown box contains duplicates. To remove them, copy that data column and paste it onto another column. Select the pasted data and click on Data menu. On the Data tools tab, select Remove duplicates. You can then create the list for the dropdown list based on the unique values.